# WPF: UI Element is NOT Updating

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, user-interface

I have a BackgroundWorker and within that worker I am reading data from an excel file. If there is an error in the excel file, the worker completes and then presents another form where the user can input the correction and then press Ok with then runs the worker again from the beginning. When the worker completes successfully it is supposed to update a label on my Mainwindow to say it has loaded the excel. But the label WILL NOT update. When I debug it I can see the code to update the label runs, but it simply does not work. 
Please help, this is driving me insane!

Here is my code.

```
    private void worker_ReadFileData(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {

        for (int j = 1; j < rcount + 1; j++) {
            worker.ReportProgress(j);

            // Do work


            if (j == 1) {
                ColumnIndex column = this.ValidateColumnIndexes(tableType);
                if (column != null) {    // If error in file, complete worker
                    fileData.isDataLoaded = false;
                    e.Result = fileData;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        fileData.isDataLoaded = true;
        e.Result = fileData;            // Pass the data to the completed method.

    }


    private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Error != null) {
        } else if (e.Cancelled) {
        } else {

            FileData fileData = (FileData) e.Result;

            if (fileData.isDataLoaded == true) {
                testLabel.Content = "It works!";
            } else {
                // Show Dialog where user can input the correction
                ColumnIndexPrompt columnIndexPrompt = new ColumnIndexPrompt(fileData.FilePath, fileData.FileExtension, fileData.TableType, fileData.Column);
                columnIndexPrompt.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    public void TriggerReadDataFile(string filePath, string fileExt, int tableType) {
        progBar.Value = 0;
        // Read the file data and populate the Registrars list, then show the datagrid
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(new FileData(filePath, fileExt, tableType));
    }
```

EDIT:
Here is the code from the second Window that I open (using .ShowDialog() in the code above)

```
    public ColumnIndexPrompt(string filePath, string fileExt, int tableType, ColumnIndex column) {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.fileExt = fileExt;
        this.tableType = tableType;
        this.column = column;

        lblColumnIndexErrorMsg.Text = column.ErrorMsg;
    }

    private void btnColumnIndexApply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MainWindow originalForm = new MainWindow();
        int correctColumnNumber = int.Parse(txtColumnIndexCorrection.Text);
        column.Index = correctColumnNumber - 1;
        originalForm.UpdateSingleColumnIndex(column);
        originalForm.TriggerReadDataFile(this.filePath, this.fileExt, this.tableType);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried using dispatcher to invoke the code to update the text?

Comment: use Live Visual Tree with Live Property Explorer to debug your Label.

Comment: @WPInfo No I haven't. To be honest I don't even know what that is sorry.

Comment: @tabby Never heard of that. I will look into it, thanks!

Comment: @mjwills Yeah, the code gets run but nothing happens. It's super weird!

Comment: @mjwills no, nothing changes. I put a breakpoint on testLabel.Content (default value is "Label") and when it runs the testLabel.Content = "It works!" line, literally nothing changes in my UI.

Comment: is there any possibility that your Label have visibility issue or it is behind any Control

Comment: @mjwills, sorry yes, the actual Content value of the variable changes to "It Works" however the UI does not change.

Comment: @tabby, nah, no visibility issues or anything, I can see it fine before I make the content change. Also, if I get rid of the code where I call columnIndexPrompt.showDialog() then the text changes successfully.

Comment: @n00bAppDev see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating MainWindow object again just change it to:

```
MainWindow mainWindow =  Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

Or

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
```

**Here:**

```
private void btnColumnIndexApply_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    MainWindow originalForm = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow; //here
    int correctColumnNumber = int.Parse(txtColumnIndexCorrection.Text);
    column.Index = correctColumnNumber - 1;
    originalForm.UpdateSingleColumnIndex(column);
    originalForm.TriggerReadDataFile(this.filePath, this.fileExt, this.tableType);
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I think you're definitely on to something! Although, when I use that code I get an error on Application.Current.MainWindow; that says: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Window' to 'MyProject.MainWindow'

Comment: whats is your startup window?

Comment: startup window is called MainWindow (namespace: MyProject)

Comment: try using (MainWindow)Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();

Comment: I was getting errors using that code. I tried: `MainWindow originalForm = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;` and it works!! WOOOOO Thanks so much!